# How to use DBContext inside WebApplicationFactory in my MSTest class/method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mstest, dbcontext

I have `CustomWebApplicationFactory` class

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram> : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    private static string conn = ""; //my connection string
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services => {
            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext>));
            if (descriptor != null)
                services.Remove(descriptor);

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options
                .UseNpgsql(conn)
                .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention()
                .UseAllCheckConstraints()
            );
        });
    }
}
```

I have this `BaseTest` class

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class BaseTest
{
    protected static CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> _webAppFactory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>();
    protected static HttpClient _httpClient = _webAppFactory.CreateDefaultClient();
    protected static ApplicationContext _context;
    private static string conn = ""; //my connection string

    [ClassInitialize(InheritanceBehavior.BeforeEachDerivedClass)]
    public static void BaseClassInitialize(TestContext context)
    {
        var dbContextOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationContext>();
        dbContextOptionsBuilder
            .UseNpgsql(conn)
            .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention()
            .UseAllCheckConstraints();

        _context = new ApplicationContext(dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options);

        _context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        _context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    [ClassCleanup(InheritanceBehavior.BeforeEachDerivedClass)]
    public static void BaseClassCleanUp()
    {
        _context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `context` in my `BaseTest` is different than the `context` inside `CustomWebApplicationFactory`. So I have issue where I don't have the updated record in my context, Example like below

```
public class CompanyTest : BaseTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task UpdateCompany_ShouldReturnOk()
    {
        //Arrange
        var company = new UpdateCompanyCommand()
        {
            Id = _companySeed.Id,
            Name = "XYZ",
            ..rest of code
        };
        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(company);

        //Act
        var response = await _httpClient.PutAsync(
            "companies",
            new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        );

        //I won't be able to get company with updated name `XYZ` here
        var updatedCompany = _context.Company.FirstOrDefault();

        ..rest of code
    }
}
```

So, my question is how do I inject/share the same `context` from my `ApplicationWebFactory` class so that I can get the latest changes in my DB?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the same context that your `CustomWebApplicationFactory` class is using.

Your `BaseTest` class would look something like this:

```cs
[TestClass]
public abstract class BaseTest
{
    protected static CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> _webAppFactory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>();
    protected static HttpClient _httpClient = _webAppFactory.CreateDefaultClient();
    protected static ApplicationContext _context = _webAppFactory.Services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationContext>();

    [ClassInitialize(InheritanceBehavior.BeforeEachDerivedClass)]
    public static void BaseClassInitialize(TestContext context)
    {
        _context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        _context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    [ClassCleanup(InheritanceBehavior.BeforeEachDerivedClass)]
    public static void BaseClassCleanUp()
    {
        _context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    }
}
```

It's important to note that the `.AddDbContext` method adds the `ApplicationContext` as a scoped service by default, so a new instance will be created each time you request the service. However, the changes I'm proposing will ensure that you are using the same configuration for the `DbContextOptions` in your integration tests as you are in the `CustomWebApplicationFactory`.

You can change the scope of the `ApplicationContext` service by adding another parameter to the `.AddDbContext` method, like so:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options
    .UseNpgsql(conn)
    .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention()
    .UseAllCheckConstraints(),
    ServiceLifetime.Singleton
);
```

Comment: the `context` is working on the `BaseTest`, but it is `null` on the `CompanyTest`. Any idea why?

Comment: I mistyped the code. Instead of `..GetRequiredService<ApplicationContext>`, I had put `...GetRequiredService<ApplicationFactory>()`, which wouldn't have compiled. I edited my answer to reflect those changes.
If it's still `null` after making those changes, then there must be a problem with the way you're wiring up your dependencies. One problem I've see is if you have multiple `ApplicationContext` classes (due to multiple projects), then make sure you're referencing the correct class in your `CustomWebApplicationFactory` class.